# How to sign using ECDSA in Javacard

Tags: signing, javacard, ecdsa

I'm trying to implement the signing code using ECDSA.
But I always get a Error SW (6F00) during install phase.
I tried by changing parameters several times. (ex. ALG_EC_FP / ALG_EC_F2M, LENGTH_EC_FP_xxx / LENGTH_EC_F2M_xxx)
Could you tell me my mistake in my code below.
(Ver - JCDK 2.2.1, JDK 1.4.2)

---

```
package Test;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.*;

public class Test extends Applet{

private byte[] PLAINTEXT ;
private ECPrivateKey objECDSAPriKey=null;   // Object for ECDSA Private Key
private ECPublicKey objECDSAPubKey=null;    // Object for ECDSA Public Key
private KeyPair objECDSAKeyPair=null;       // Object for ECDSA Key Pair
private Signature objECDSASign=null;        // Object for ECDSA Signature

final static short BAS =  0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength){
  new Test(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
}

private Test(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength){ 
  PLAINTEXT = new byte[0x100] ; // Data file
  Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(PLAINTEXT,  BAS, (short)0x100, (byte)0);

  // Error position (6F00)
  objECDSAKeyPair= new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192);          // Error position (6F00)

  // Create Signature Object
  objECDSASign = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, false);

  register();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void process(APDU apdu){
  byte buf[] = apdu.getBuffer();

  switch(buf[1])
  {
  case (byte)0xA4: break;

  case (byte)0x46:
  objECDSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();
  objECDSAPriKey = (ECPrivateKey)objECDSAKeyPair.getPrivate();
  objECDSAPubKey = (ECPublicKey)objECDSAKeyPair.getPublic();
  break;

  case (byte)0x2E:
  short Le = apdu.setOutgoing();
  short sSignLen=0 ;

  // Init with Private Key
  objECDSASign.init(objECDSAPriKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
  //objECDSASign.init(objECDSAKeyPair.getPrivate(), Signature.MODE_SIGN);

  // Sign Data
  sSignLen = objECDSASign.sign(PLAINTEXT, BAS, Le, buf, BAS);

  apdu.setOutgoingLength(sSignLen);
  apdu.sendBytes(BAS, sSignLen);
  break;

  default:
  ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
  }

  return;
} }
```

---

I got a JCOP card and its specification, and I read that the card support ECC in the spec.
But I doubt that the spec is the card's spec and the card really support ECC.
Is there any way to check that???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify when exactly you get the error? During applet installation through GlobalPlatform card manager? If yes, during loading the package or during installing (making selectable) the applet? Or when sending one of your custom APDU commands to your applet?

Comment: At this line of installation phase -------->
objECDSAKeyPair= new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192);
And I changed the parameter but I got error(6F00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please modify your code to

```
try
  {
     // Error position (6F00)
     objECDSAKeyPair= new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192); 
  }
  catch(CryptoException c)
  {    
      //this line will give you the reason of problem ![see image][1]
      byte reason = c.getReason();   
  }
```

*image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFXVd.png

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are my hero. I got the reason code 3 (NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM). I can tell the person who give me the card about that. Thank you again. ^^