# Get the reason of CryptoException in JavaCard

Tags: smartcard, javacard, ecdsa

I am trying to implement ECDSA in JavaCard (Eclipse 4.4.2, JC 2.2.1). My card is a Gemalto IDCore 3010, or at least it is supposed to be (after checking the ATR code it looks like, that it is a WM GX4 72 DHS TSA...).

Anyway, if I don't surround the *objECDSAKeyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192)* line with try and catch I get an unknown error (*send_APDU() returns 0x80206F00 (Unknown ISO7816 error: 0x6F00)*), but when I do surround it, it returns no error (*send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)*). However it must go to the catch block because the other three lines in the try block don't get executed.

**How can I visualize the error message?** If I go with *ISOException.throwIt(reason)*, I get *Communication error with the intelligent card. Please try it again.* multiple times.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066444/how-to-sign-using-ecdsa-in-javacard) thread it suggests the *byte reason = c.getReason()* code, but it won't work, not even if I cast the right side to byte.

Thank you!

Here is the relevant part of my code.

```
public class ECDSATestApplet extends Applet {

    private final static byte CLS = (byte) 0xE0;
    private final static byte NOOP = (byte) 0x00;
    private final static byte GEN = (byte) 0x01;

    ...

    private final static byte[] HELLO_WORLD = new byte[] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!' };

    private ECPrivateKey objECDSAPriKey = null;
    private ECPublicKey objECDSAPubKey = null;
    private KeyPair objECDSAKeyPair = null;
    private Signature objECDSASign = null;

    final static short BAS = 0;

    private ECDSATestApplet() {
    }

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new ECDSATestApplet().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (this.selectingApplet())
            return;

        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLS)
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
        case NOOP:
            break;

        case GEN:
            try {
                // ------- ERROR LINE -------
                objECDSAKeyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192);
//              objECDSASign = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, false);
//              objECDSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();
//              objECDSAPriKey = (ECPrivateKey) objECDSAKeyPair.getPrivate();
//              objECDSAPubKey = (ECPublicKey) objECDSAKeyPair.getPublic();
                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(HELLO_WORLD, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) HELLO_WORLD.length);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) HELLO_WORLD.length);
            } catch (CryptoException c) {
                short reason = c.getReason();
//              ISOException.throwIt(reason);
            }

            break;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use `byte reason = c.getReason() `? Does it returns any error? when? in installation process? or in runtime?

Comment: Reason is a number between 0 and 5. It can be confusing for the reader if your card returns 0x0001 as the status word, for example. Try throwing ISOException.throwIt((short) (0x9C00 + reason)) instead.

Comment: There should be "between 1 and 5" in my previous comment, sorry.

Comment: @vojta _It can be confusing for the reader_ : for the reader or for the application on the computer?

Comment: @TheGoodUser For the reader, really. Readers can try to process the status word, as they sometimes do with 61xx or 6Cxx, unfortunately. In your applet you should only use status words from the interval dedicated by ISO7816 (or ETSI standard on SIM cards).

Comment: @vojta I wrote a javacard applet that returns `0x0001` on respond of APDU Select command and upload it on two different cards. Now, when I select my applet on card A, it returns `0x0001` successfully and when I select the same applet in the second card and using the same reader, the transmission fails. So I think sometimes it is related to the card also. i.e. all the failures when we use SW=0x0001 are not related to the reader only. right?

Comment: @TheGoodUser Yes, you are right. I just wanted to say it is not wise to use status words out of the interval mentioned in standards (ISO, ETSI), because it can cause some mysterious bugs dependent on readers (my experience) and cards (your experience).

Comment: @Abraham I get this error: `unsupported String type constant.` and this:  `unsupported parameter type String of invoked method <init>(java.lang.String) of class java.lang.Error.`. Eclipse promts me to add cast to 'byte'. 
@vojta With your version I get this: `unsupported int type constant.`.

Comment: @bp14 Clean and rebuild the entire project...

Comment: @bp14 Sorry, this should work: ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) (0x9C00) | reason))

Comment: Thanks! I got 9C03, so _no such algorithm_. Just to be sure, I checked also `KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512)` and it worked, so it looks like the card doesn't support ECDSA.

Comment: @bp14 and what about ECC over F2M, did you try that? Smart cards usually support only one of these EC variants.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I checked for example this: `new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_F2M , KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_F2M_113)`, and the error code is 9C03 again.

Comment: @vojta If you put this code as an answer I can accept it.
`ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) (0x9C00) | reason))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible reasons of your troubles:

1. Your status word does not follow status words recommended by ISO7816. Try

   ```
   ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) (0x9C00) | reason));
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   ISOException.throwIt(reason);
   ```
2. You forgot to set parameters of your elliptic curve before generating a new key pair. You should generate your EC key pair this way:

   ```
   KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_EC_FP, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_EC_FP_192);
   ECPrivateKey privKey = (ECPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
   ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
   initDomainParams(pubKey);
   initDomainParams(privKey);
   keyPair.genKeyPair();
   ```

   where

   ```
   private void initDomainParams(ECKey key) {
       key.setFieldFP(F, (short)0, (short)F.length);
       key.setA(A, (short)0, (short)A.length);
       key.setB(B, (short)0, (short)B.length);
       key.setG(G, (short)0, (short)G.length);
       key.setR(R, (short)0, (short)R.length);
   }
   ```

   with `F`, `A`, `B`, `G`, `R` parameters of the elliptic curve you have chosen for your signature. See the list of recommended curves here: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/dss/NISTReCur.pdf